# Can a non-aggregate class with deleted constructors and destructor be ever instantiated?

Tags: c++, object, casting, instantiation, c++17

Consider the following class:

```
template <class T>
class object {
public:
    using type = T;

    object() = delete;
    object(const object&) = delete;
    object(object&&) = delete;
    object& operator=(const object&) = delete;
    object& operator=(object&&) = delete;
    ~object() = delete;

private:
    type value = 0;
};
```

Is it possible to instantiate an object (on the stack (probably not) or on the heap (maybe?)) of type `object<int>` by any weird trickery, or is it impossible for an `object<int>` to ever exist in any conceivable (well formed and with well defined behavior) `C++17` program?

Addendum: First we consider non ill-formed NDR programs/non undefined behavior. If and only if, there are only ill-formed NDR programs/undefined behavior programs possible, you can illustrate the answer with such a program.

Comment: May I ask, how is this useful?

Comment: @PasserBy This is mostly a theoretical question

Comment: `object<int>` may be instantiated if you write a **specialization** for it which allow it. Cannot be instanitated from that generic class.

Comment: You can create a `void*` pointer and cast it to `object<T>*`, right? This is a defined behaviour, isn't it? Although not a defined value.

Comment: @freakish No it's not.

Comment: @PasserBy The standard explicitely allows casting from `void*` to any pointer type. How is that not a defined behaviour? Or am I wrong about it?

Comment: @freakish - There isn't an object there. Not for a type like this, anyway.

Comment: @PasserBy you could use this for a collection of static functions ... most people would put them in a namespace as free functions but here's an alternative.

Comment: Create a buffer and use a cast. This way without initializing or destructing, an object can be used. Answer attached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it cannot. From [[basic.life]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.life)

> [...] The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - if the object has non-vacuous initialization, its initialization is complete,

Thus initialization must be performed. We then look at [all the possible initializations](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17).

1. If the initializer is `{...}`, then it is [list-initialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list).

   - The class is non-aggregate, so it cannot be [aggregate-initialized](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.aggr).
   - The class has no default constructor, so it can't be value-initialized by `{}`
   - The class can be direct-initialized or copy-initialized by a `{x}`, which calls a constructor through overload resolution
2. If the initializer is `()`, then it is value-initialized
3. If the initializer is the same cv-unqualified type, the initializer expression for the initializer is used instead as the initializer

   - That is, `T x = T(T());` is just to default-initialize `x`, with no copies
4. If there is no initializers, then it is default-initialized
5. Otherwise constructors are considered and called with overload resolution.
6. To value-initialize is to default-initialize the object in this case.
7. Default-initialization calls the default constructor in this case.

If you look carefully, there is only one way on this list to initialize the object, and that is to call a constructor. Since we have deleted all constructors, we can't initialize the object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't claim this to be an answer (am not a language lawyer), just post some findings from n4659:

> 11.6.20: An object whose initialization has completed is deemed to be constructed, even if no constructor of the object’s class is invoked for the initialization. [ Note: **Such an object might have been value-initialized** or
>   initialized by aggregate initialization (11.6.1) or by an inherited constructor (15.6.3). —end note ]

From the 3 options mentioned in the note, only the first applies:

> 11.6.8: To **value-initialize** an object of type T means ... (8.1) — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 12) with either no default constructor (15.1) **or a default constructor that is** user-provided or **deleted**, then the object is **default-initialized**;

Since a default constructor is deleted:

> 11.6.7: To **default-initialize** an object of type T means ... (7.1) — If T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 12), constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (16.3.1.3), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution (16.3). **The constructor thus selected is called**, with an empty argument list, to initialize the object.

Since there is no constructor that can be called, I think the instance of class `object` cannot be constructed.

Answer (score -1):

The rules are clear, this object cannot be initialized correctly.

Since that is what is asked for, then create a buffer for Your class, and use it with care.

```
template< typename T >
class object_wrapper
{
    std::byte buffer[ sizeof( T ) ];

public:
    auto& inner() { return *reinterpret_cast< T* >( buffer ); }
};
```

Here is an example:

```
int main()
{
    //object< int > o; // impossible

    object_wrapper< object< int > > ow; // wrap the object

    object< int >& o( ow.inner() );     // possible

    o.some_foo();

}
```